# Running soft linked node script as cmd. can't find installed modules

Tags: node.js, linux, bash

I have a node script that running perfect inside the same project folder let's say start.js that uses the puppeteer library and it's running perfect as the following :
node start.js

what I'm trying to do is linking this command to use it anywhere inside the server

`chmod +x /var/www/wc-service/spa/start.js && ln -s /var/www/wc-service/spa/bin/start.js /usr/bin/mycommand`

but when running the new command from the bash, I got this error
Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises' from inside node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserFetcher.js:36:20)

Notes

node:  v21.1.0
Debian GNU/Linux 11
npm : 10.2.3

node is updated and have 'fs/promises' by default
any would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: You're chmodding it to be executable before the link, how are you running it without the link? By calling `node start.js`? Is there a shebang in `start.js`?

Comment: @leitning yes by calling node start.js and yes there is a shebang  (#!/usr/bin/node
) in  start.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are running v21.x I assume you compiled and installed your own node. `require('fs/promises')` is a relatively new addition, if you built `node` into the `/usr/local` path (which I think is default) it would explain all your symptoms.

Running `node start.js` would use the the executable at `/usr/local/bin/node` and be fine since it's on version 21.x; while adding the `/usr/bin/node` shebang would fail since it's on an older version from the Debian repo that does not support the `require('fs/promises')` call.

You can verify this by running `which node` in the terminal to check where the executable you're running with `node start.js` is located.

Also, there's no reason the symlink should cause a failure, I imagine you would get the same result by just trying to run `./start.js`.